# Adding twisted code to a pygtk app

Tags: python, pygtk, twisted

I have a simple pygtk app using urllib2, what changes should I make to add working twisted code?

The pbgtk2.py example it's confusing

Comment: -1: No code here, either.  That's confusing, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You switch from using the gtk mainloop to the right [Twisted reactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/choosing-reactor.html#auto11). Or you decide to run Twisted in a separate thread using [reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0), and stay with the gtk mainloop](http://unpythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/what-twisted-could-learn-from-kamaelia.html).

You decide if you want to defer the urllib2 call to [its own thread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.deferToThread.html), or if you want to rewrite that code using [Twisted's HTTP client libraries](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.web.client.html).

You go to the Twisted mailing list or IRC channel and [ask for help](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedCommunity).